# ESP32 partition 3mb Spiff and 1mb App not applied [PlatformIO]

Tags: esp32, platformio

Im using a custom partition file for esp32 using PlatformIO addon for VS Code. The intent is to alocate 3mb to spiff and 1mb for app.
The partition file is noota_3g.csv with content

```
# Name,   Type, SubType, Offset,  Size, Flags
nvs,      data, nvs,     0x9000,  0x5000,
otadata,  data, ota,     0xe000,  0x2000,
app0,     app,  ota_0,   0x10000, 0x100000,
spiffs,   data, spiffs,  0x110000,0x2F0000,
```

This should enable to make filesystem that is 3mb but when I try to build filesystem using PlatformIO I get error SPIFFS_write error(-10001): File system is full.
As soon as /data folder is above 2.200kb I get this error.

If I try other partitions they act as expected, only when I try to make it above 2mb.
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by adding

board_build.filesystem = littlefs

to platformio.ini